# Communicate with a windows batch file (or external program) from java

Tags: java, windows

I know there are similar threads, and I have read them all. However none of them have been of any help.

I have this simple batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p UserInput=Enter a number: 
echo Number was %UserInput%
```

I want to run this batch file from java, send the number to it and get the input.

I have a strange problem. I started the batch file using cmd /c, opened the input and output streams, but it still won't work. When I run a program, for example "cmd.exe", it returns the actual output that you get when you open a CMD window:

> Microsoft Windows...  Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.

So at least the code is partially working. However it simply does not give me ANY output whatsoever when I use `"cmd /c C:\\test.bat"` (where test.bat is a valid batch file).

This is the java code. What's wrong with it?

```
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

    public class Test {

        private static BufferedReader bufIn;
        private static BufferedWriter printOut;
        private static Process p;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;

            p = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c C:\\test.bat");
            InputStream in = p.getInputStream() ;
            OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream ();

            bufIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            printOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

            int ch = 0;
            ch = bufIn.read();

            while (ch != 0) 
            {
                System.out.print((char) ch);
                ch = bufIn.read();
            }

            //send a command to 

            printOut.write("209");
            printOut.flush();

            while (ch != 0) 
            {
                System.out.print((char) ch);
                ch = bufIn.read();
            }



    //p.destroy() ;

    }


}
```

I should be getting:

> ```
> Please enter a number:
> Number was 209
> ```

Edit: I edited the code because it was apparently getting stuck at the readLine while there was no line :)

Anyway, I still have a problem.
I'm getting:

```
Enter a number:
```

and nothing else, almost as if the output stream is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a PrintWriter, try an OutputStreamWriter wrapped in a BufferedWriter:

```
printOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
```

Obviously you'll need to change `printOut` to a BufferedWriter as well.

It also looks like you're flushing and printing in the wrong order to me, I'd do:

```
printOut.println("209");
printOut.flush();
```

As a side point, you can use `readLine()` on BufferedReader rather than just `read()`!

Comment: @David you have to use write - did you add a newline character after your command? i.e. `printOut.writer("209\n");`

Comment: printOut.write("209 \n"); did not work :( It still gets stuck on "Enter a number:" However it looks like it's getting stuck in the while loop. As I said before readLine() was causing it to get stuck (because in the batch file there is "Enter a number:" not "Enter a number:\n"), therefore it never moved past that point. Any ideas?

Comment: ARGHHH I give up. I'm just going to run them on separate threads and get it over and done with. I'll mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: Don't you need to call `ch = bufIn.read();` before the second while loop? Otherwise it'll just have the last value in from the first while loop, which will be 0 - therefore it'll skip right past the second loop. do..while loops might be better in this instance.

Comment: It's never getting past the first while loop!!! It's stopping at ch = bufIn.read(); Also, I tried running them on different threads to no avail. Can you compile it and try it out and see?