# Why is my code to enter input to a batch file not working?

Tags: java, batch-file, stream, return, output

I'm trying to write to a loaded batch file process, but I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent of a return.

Java Code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Max\\Desktop\\test.bat");// Runtime.getRuntime().exec("keytool -genkey -alias " + name.replace(" ", "").trim() + "  -keystore key");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            // System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            out.write("test\n\n".getBytes());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Batch code:

```
@echo off
set /p delBuild=lozors?: 
echo test >> test.txt
```

When run, it should output to a text file on my desktop... but it doesn't seem to take the input? I've tried using \n and \n\n, as well as just writing and flushing, but it doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: Why use a DataOutputStream when you're writing text? Why not use a PrintStream and simply use its `println(...)` method to write new lines?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  The `test.bat` doesn't read any input.

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to take the input?"* But why should it? Firstly the batch file is not expecting any input

Comment: It does when I open it? I'll try using a printwriter.

Comment: If I open the batch file and type text and hit enter, it writes a text file on the desktop? Also, the PrintWriter did not work.

Comment: Yep, second @MadProgrammer's comment.

Comment: The batch file is writing the string `test` to the end of `test.txt`.  It will do this regardless of what you type on the command line.

Comment: I also "suspect" that by the time you've read the input from the process it may have already stopped executing...

Comment: What do you mean it's not expecting input? Your telling me that somethings wrong without explaining WHAT is wrong? The only reason I have the input in the batch file is so that I can prove that java is writing to the batch file input.

Comment: What do you think should your batch do? What is the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, appologise, I'm not a batch developer and it's being a long time since I've done any (serious) batch coding, so I didn't recognize the `set /p` command...

There might be a number of reason WHY you code isn't working, but the obvious thing that stands out is this command in your batch file...

```
echo test >> test.txt
```

Which is "echoing" `test` to `test.txt`.  It's not echoing what you have typed.

To do that, you need to echo the environment variable `delBuild`, which your input will be assigned to.

```
echo %delBuild% >> test.txt
```

Also note, that once you send `\n`, its likely that the text will be committed to the environment variable and the batch file will continue to run.

This is the batch file I used in my testing...

```
@echo off
set /p delBuild=lozors?: 
echo %delBuild% >> test.txt
```

This is the code I used to test it with...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class TestProcessBuilder02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.bat");
            pb.redirectError();
            Process p = pb.start();

            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                os = p.getOutputStream();
                os.write("I am invincible".getBytes());
            } finally {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = p.getInputStream();
                int in = -1;
                while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char)in);
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            int exit = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with " + exit);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Note- I've used `ProcessBuilder` as it generally easier and more forgiving the trying to use `Runtime#exec` on it's own - IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I actually just used the answer at: [Communicate with a windows batch file (or external program) from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969305/communicate-with-a-windows-batch-file-or-external-program-from-java?rq=1) except, I didn't use the bufferedwriter as it seemed to stop it from working.