# Desktop.getDeskto().open(batch file) does not work sometimes

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, apache-commons

I am having two issues in the following code

```
File export=new File("C:\\testdir"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\\export.bat");
try 
{
    FileUtils.write(export, "mini_server_11\\udrive\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -proot static_gatetest > C:\\testdir"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\\admin.sql", false);
} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to create file");
    Logger.getLogger(adminsetting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return;
}
//Execute bat file
try 
{
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(export);
} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to launch file");
    Logger.getLogger(adminsetting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return;
}
try 
{
    //Delete bat file. No worries. this file will be overwritten when next attempt
    //to build installer takes place
    FileUtils.forceDelete(export);
} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(adminsetting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I am using Apache Common IO for creating batch file on the fly.

1. First Issue is Desktop.getdesktop.open() sometimes run the batch file successfully and sometimes doesnt. Batch file is always created as I can see the cmd window. But it quits very quickly and not .sql file is created. No exception is thrown too. It seems like batch file was created, opened but didnt execute.
2. Second issue is, FileUtils.forceDelete always raises as exception. I dont know what's wrong. Everything i according to manual I found on internet. I tried deletequietly() too, but it also says unable to delete the file.

My apologies for indentation problem. I still cant figure out how to properly write code in SO

Comment: Try using a `ProcessBuilder`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198787/why-is-my-code-to-enter-input-to-a-batch-file-not-working/18198972#18198972)

Comment: Okay I will try ProcessBuilder. But, the only thing I worry is how can I test the "sometimes problem" happening. Is there any issue with Desktop.getDesktop.open() opening batch file? Same code works 50-60% of the time...

Comment: @MadProgrammer : can `getRuntime().exec()` be used here, instead of `Desktop.getDesktop().open()`?

Comment: It's hard to tell, because you've lost the possibility to process the error output (if any) from either the batch file or the sql command.  Using `ProcessBuilder` could also do away with the need for the batch file ;)

Comment: @SiddharthM `ProcessBuilder` would be preferred, as it has better support for redirection of the err/stdout and the ability to specify a working directory context for example - but that's just MHO

Comment: JOptionPane.show... should be wrapped into invokeLater, more to see in Oracle tutorial EventDispatchThread and Initial Thread

Comment: How do I process error Output in ProcessBuilder. I havent used it earlier and have little knowledge about it. I found a reason for unexpected behavior. After deleting the lines that deletes the batch file created on the fly, it works properly. So I guess it depends on which runs first, batch file or deletion statement of the java. Can I make java to pause its execution until the execution statement is completed. Thanks for your concern @MadProgrammer

Comment: Did you have a look at the posted [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198787/why-is-my-code-to-enter-input-to-a-batch-file-not-working/18198972#18198972)?  Basically the example redirects the stderr of the process through the stdout and you can read the `Process` `InputStream`